# Flask App runs in terminal but not in Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

So, I've got this flask app that works fine when I run it via the terminal, but for some reason, if I start up a docker container, it instantly exits with 'exit code zero'.

Here is the folder structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgM10.jpg

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.2'

services:

    flask-app:
        build: ./Flask_App
        volumes:
            - ./Flask_App/static:/Flask_App/static
            - ./Flask_App/db:/Flask_App/db
        ports:
            - '5001:5001'
        # restart: unless-stopped
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

# Setup env
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Setup App
RUN mkdir -p /Flask_App

COPY . /Flask_App

WORKDIR /Flask_App

EXPOSE 5001

ENTRYPOINT [ 'python3' ]

CMD [ 'app.py' ]
```

and the app.py file: (I know its just imports, but it works fine when I run it via the terminal on the host, so it probably is working ok)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

from forms import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
Bootstrap(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

from views import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=app.config['HOST'], port=app.config['PORT'], debug=app.config['DEBUG'])
```

and just in case, here is a part of the 'config.py' file:

```
DEBUG = False
HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 5001
```

Comment: `docker logs containerid` will show the logs of the container, please paste that as well. Or if you run docker run without the -d option also will shows the logs in stdout.

Comment: Does changing the single quotes to double quotes in the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` lines fix things?  They are supposed to be JSON arrays.

Comment: no f* way this worked, it was just the quotes in `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`

Answer (score 0):

As said by [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) in a comment, the single quotes(`'`) I used in `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` should be changed to double quotes (`"`), since they are supposed to be JSON arrays.